# scrapyd stops after one second without error messages in logfile

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I am running scrapyd 1.2 with scrapy version 2.1 and suddenly the daemon stoped working properly. It will schedule jobs, but they end after one second to status "finished" and the log file of this spider shows this as the last line:

```
2020-05-17 07:28:56 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: d65ea0bd25f75ea0
```

There is no exit message or error message why it stopped or failed.

I installed spidermon yesterday among with other things, but on the development server everything runs OK and the production server successfully finished another job, started several hours ago. Just new spiders will fail now.

In the meantime I stoped the daemon and started it again which now outputs logs directly in the terminal.

Scheduling a spider returns:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spidermon'
```

So clearly the install did not work as expected.

Now it boils down to two questions:

1. How to configure scrapyd to write a sys logfile to /var/logs/scrapyd/
2. How to install spidermon

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by uninstalling spidermon and reinstalling system wide:

sudo pip3 uninstall spidermon

sudo -H pip3 install spidermon

The logfile problematic is unresolved but to be fair not part of this question.

Comment: I did run into the same problem about 2 years later. In the new case I installed slack and slackclient modules for python. This somehow did lead to the same problem. Uninstall and Reinstall Spidermon fixed it.